# How do I promote other users to the System Admin role in Mattermost?

Tags: mattermost

The Mattermost documentation [states](https://docs.mattermost.com/help/getting-started/managing-members.html#system-admin) that a user with the role of System Admin can promote other users to that same role since version 3.0.

Looking through the Web UI and browsing the documentation however leaves me clueless how to achieve that. Can anyone point me to the proper place in the Web UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can be promoted to System Admins by another System Admin as follows:

1. Click on 3-dot Main Menu
2. Select System Console
3. Scroll down until you see "Teams" and click on the "+"
4. Find the team the user you want to promote belongs to and select that team
5. That team will now be displayed in the left-hand-side bar below "Teams"
6. Click on "Users"
7. Search for the user
8. Click on the dropdown displayed to the righ of the user's name
9. Promote the user to System admin

Hope this helps!